# AzureML: Unable to unpickle LightGBM model

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run an Azure ML pipeline. This pipeline trains a model, saves it a pickle file and then tries to unpickle it in the next step. When trying to unpickle it, I am facing the below issue in any random run:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "batch_scoring.py", line 199, in 
>       clf = joblib.load(open(model_path, 'rb'))
>     File "/azureml-envs/azureml_347514cea2002d6bd71b42aceb1e4eeb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 595, in load
>       obj = _unpickle(fobj)
>     File "/azureml-envs/azureml_347514cea2002d6bd71b42aceb1e4eeb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 529, in _unpickle
>       obj = unpickler.load()
>     File "/azureml-envs/azureml_347514cea2002d6bd71b42aceb1e4eeb/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 1048, in load
>       raise EOFError
>   EOFError

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the pipeline/code that you are trying?

Comment: So first I train different models using azureml HyperDriveStep and then downloading the best model using the below code:           `run_best.download_file('outputs/{}.pkl'.format(args.model_name), output_file_path="./outputs")`                                                                                         This model is then unpickled in the next pipeline step using the model code: `clf = joblib.load(open(model_path, 'rb'))`

Comment: unpickle can easily fail if the version of the pickled objects' python package differs between saving and loading. Are you using the same environment for both steps? I guess the most important ones being the versions of a) lightgbm and b) joblib.

Comment: Yes, using the same version.

Comment: @DanielSchneider @user12580137 I opened an issue on `joblib`'s GitHub, though I'm still not sure what the root cause is... https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12271

Answer (score 0):

I get same error when I m trying to unpickle the model from output folder/ model registry. In my case the pkl was not properly formed during the experiment. Try to re-run the experiment (I did it without changing any line and it works for me). In my case even the first pickle was a smaller size than the good one. Hope this helps :)